# Run smooth continuous rotation animation of spinner using animator

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to run my spinner rotation animation smoothly. At present its rotating one round then after taking short break and then after again start rotation.

I have recorded video for this purpose, here you have the link:
[spinner rotation](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MOuwyb5sMT_jZLuqFaeTBSFp5B7A0frr)

I want to always rotate spinner with same speed without taking any pause, give me some suggestion into this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to `Window -> Animation`. Then select start and end animation keyframes and right click on it; Now select `Both Tangents` and click on `Linear` (Like this image):

[image]

I hope it helps you

Comment: yes after this curves become straight and animation started playing normally rather than jump and pause...